# Setting Samba Share HDD Space available to Win10

Tags: samba, centos7

Little bit new to Linux/Centos7 working with Samba.

I have a XFS LVM (spanned over 2 internal harddrives).

```
Filesystem                    1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root        52403200 50467380    1935820  97% /
devtmpfs                        3961956        0    3961956   0% /dev
tmpfs                           3977436       80    3977356   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           3977436     9208    3968228   1% /run
tmpfs                           3977436        0    3977436   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home       427041048    90040  426951008   1% /home
/dev/sdc1                        508588   216820     291768  43% /boot
tmpfs                            795488        8     795480   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                            795488       48     795440   1% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/lvm_pool-Storage 2928843508    32976 2928810532   1% /run/media/root/e6072a3d-a27d-4b7f-9b77-a4594950d5e5
```

Successfully set up Samba Shares which I can easily access from Windows 10, but of the 3TB storage on the HDD, the share on Windows can only see 50GB.

Wondering if there is a setting in Centos7 (64-bit) to allow my Samba Share to make the whole 3TB available to my windows share?

Testparm Dump if relevant (which I assume it most certainly is)

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    netbios name = MYECOM-MEDIA
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    security = USER
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    hosts allow = 127. 192.168.


[Plex-Storage]
    path = /mnt/hdd/Plex-Storage
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

Comment: Apologies if this is supposed to be in ServerFault or Superuser??

Comment: It is in ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved question to Unix/Linux and got the answer.... simply my HDD was mounted to the wrong folder.

Problem solved.